# How to display a label for a specific post in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a jobs plugin which enables the user to search its database. Somehow, I've managed to hide the search catagory which required `full-time, part-time` input to search the database properly. This is what I want because it cluttered the page. However, on the listing itself I'd like to show the `full-time/part-time etc` label, as well as on the individual page.

At the moment the catagory label does show up on the single page when a viewer is looking at the job details, but it disappears straightaway again and no `full-time etc`catagory is listed on the main jobs page where all the job listings are.

So how do I?

A) find the correct css selector for this label?
B) Display it on single page ads as well as in the site listings section?

View [here](https://adsler.co.uk/jobs/)

Html 
    `<li><label for="job_type_full-time" class="full-time"><input 
    type="checkbox" name="filter_job_type[]" value="full-time"

    checked='checked' id="job_type_full-time" /> Full 
    Time</label></li>`

Css tried:

`label[for="job_type_full-time"] {
    visibilty: visible !important; display:unset !important;  }`

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this from a PHP angle!

Just setup an if statement to match the Post ID you're trying to target

```
<?php if($post->ID == 555): ?>
<label class="full-time">
  <input 
    type="checkbox" name="filter_job_type[]" value="full-time"
    checked='checked' id="job_type_full-time" /> Full Time
</label>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks? Put in functions?

Comment: No this would go in to one of your theme's template files: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#common-wordpress-template-files

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In worpress, the post page has many usefull classes that will help you.

If you look at the  tag, you will see something like this:

```
<body class="product-template-default single single-product postid-17717 logged-in admin-bar theme-genesis woocommerce woocommerce-page woocommerce-js header-full-width content-sidebar genesis-singular-image-hidden theme-boldfun customize-support" >
```

There you can see things like the type of post, and the post ID.

You can use this class to target your label:

```
body.postid-17717 label.full-time{
    visibilty: visible !important; 
    display:unset !important;  
}
```

This will select the <label class="full-time"> only in the post 17717